# How is my friend bypassing Applock application

Tags: security, password

I'm using moto x 2nd gen, I recently installed applock to keep some apps private but one of my friend knows a way to bypass the password and even change it, he did the same even with pattern lock. He doesn't even reboot the phone, he does it in seconds. How is he doing it and in what other ways can I lock my apps?

Comment: Have you thought about asking him?

Comment: Could you link the app? There are some apps that have similar name like "AppLock", is it the one by DoMobile?

Answer (score 2):

One possible answer can be that he is killing the application process that is protecting your device. One possible way is that he goes to Settings->Apps->[applock_application] and then Force Stop it.

Go to this [link](http://www.triadsquare.com/how-to-bypass-applock-in-android-device) for more detail.

Comment: I've locked settings and play store too.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to bypass applock, you can reboot into safe mode, uninstall/force stop/clear data the applock (if Settings is not locked), widgets (some apps have a Task Manager widget or Enable/Disable app widget), using third party application to uninstall/force stop/clear data the applock, uninstall the applock from Google Play Store (if Play Store is not locked), if Play Store is locked, open Google Play Store website from any browser, then uninstall the applock, etc. These only works on non-system applock, to bypass system applock, you have to disable/force stop the applock, or factory data reset.

Answer (score 0):

He either knows your pin and your pattern or He killed the apps process ( applock ) to bypass the pin or he set "destroy process after user leaves it" in the developer options.

Comment: He can't stop the app process, I locked the settings too.